# How to align content in columns using spacing, tabs or padding?

Tags: c#, string, line, itext, padding

i'm trying to create a pdf looks like this

[image: look like1]

but when i try string padding, it looks like this in pdf file
[image: look like2]

here is the part of the c# code i tried. myExcelData is filled from excel file.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            Chunk cSira = new Chunk((i + 1).ToString().PadRight(10), icerikFont);
            Chunk cHizmet = new Chunk(myExcelData.Tables[0].Rows[i][6].ToString().PadRight(80), icerikFont);
            Chunk cAdet = new Chunk(myExcelData.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString().PadRight(10), icerikFont);
            Chunk cBirimFiyat = new Chunk(myExcelData.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString().PadRight(20), icerikFont);
            Chunk cTutar = new Chunk(myExcelData.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString().PadRight(20), icerikFont);
            d.Add(cSira);
            d.Add(cHizmet);
            d.Add(cAdet);
            d.Add(cBirimFiyat);
            d.Add(cTutar);
            d.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        }
```

Comment: And the question is..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. use a monospaced font (e.g. Courier). Currently you're using a font of which the width of the different characters is different.
2. download [chapter 2 of my book](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf) and learn how to use TAB CHUNKS (look for that title on page 48).
3. Use a PdfPTable as mkl indicates in his comment (maybe you were overlooking the obvious)

If you need a code snippet for option 2, take a look at the [DirectorOverview3](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=45) example. The result looks like [this](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter02/director_overview_3.pdf). If you don't understand Java, read the [C# example](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter02/DirectorOverview3.cs).

Comment: thanks. i've tried first one and result is;
[like this](http://i.imgur.com/GNKdKaJ.png)
i'll also try other ones tomorrow.